# Where's the memory leak?

Tags: pointers, memory-leaks, pointer-arithmetic

So I'm learning pointers and having a difficult time identifying the memory leak here. I confess I have never used malloc() before and am new to pointer arithmetic. Thanks in advance.

```c
 /*filename: p3.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
        char *buffer;
        char *p;
        int n;

        /* allocate 10 bytes */
        buffer = (char *) malloc(10);

        p = buffer;
        for (n=0; n<=10; n++)
                *p++ = '*';

        p = buffer;
        for (n=0; n <=10; n++)
                printf("%c ", *p++);

        return 0;
}
```

Comment: And you're writing out of bounds, you have only space for 10 `char`s, but write 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to **free** your buffer by using the `free()` function, when you don't need the buffer anymore:

```
    /* ... */
    free( buffer );
    return 0;
}
```

Simply remember to **balance** each call to `malloc` with a call to `free`, **when the memory is not used anymore**.

The operations on your `p` variable won't affect `buffer`. They are two pointers pointing to the **same area** (at start), but they're still **two distinct variables**. So incrementing `p` won't increment `buffer`.
So nothing wrong with the pointer operations on `p`, except the fact you are **writing out of bounds**, as stated by *Daniel Fisher* in the comments of your question.

Also note that you should also always **check for `NULL`**, after the `malloc` call, as `malloc` may fail. It's pretty rare nowadays, but if it fails, your program will probably crash, as you will then dereference a `NULL` pointer:

```
buffer = malloc( 10 );

if( buffer == NULL )
{
    /* Error management - Do not use buffer */
}
```

The cast to `char *` is not needed on `malloc`, unless you are dealing with C++. In C, it's valid to assign a `void pointer` to another pointer type.

Answer (score 3):

The rule is rather simple, for every malloc there must be a free. If you have more mallocs than frees you forgot to de-allocate memory and so you have a memory leak. If you have more frees than mallocs you're trying to de-allocate memory that has already been de-allocated and that's not something you want.

Answer (score 2):

You call `malloc` and never call `free`. Of course it leaks.

In principle, every single allocation you request from the `alloc` family of function should be `free`ed as soon as you are done with them.

Buffers that you continue to use to up to the termination of the program are *formally* leaks, but not a problem as long as you are allocating a well defined number of them. That includes what you are doing here.

Answer (score 2):

It is not n<=10 you want, but n<10.